# Pokemon mesh breaks apart during animation

Tags: modeling, animation, cycles-render-engine, mesh, rigging

[image]

I'm reapplying Pokémon animations to their respective models. However, when I reapply them, the mesh breaks apart. I tried merging the mesh *Mesh>Merge>By Distance*, but no luck.

blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FHOADOMJwoq_T3Yb_w69cESij1OBKjIy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Sorry I'm bad at this. Here you go!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FHOADOMJwoq_T3Yb_w69cESij1OBKjIy/view?usp=sharing